# django : url tag -> how to use a variable as url_name?

Tags: django

I have a django view which declare a target variable :

```
target  = "name_of_next_view_to_call"
return render(request, template, locals() )
```

I want to use this target variable into my template, I tried the following :

```
<form action="{% url '{{target}}' %}" method="post">
```

which gives me an error :

```
Reverse for '{{target}}' not found. '{{target}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How to use the value of my "target" variable as the name of the url to be constructed ? 
From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/) I know it should be possible :

> The first argument is a URL pattern name. It can be a quoted literal
>   or any other context variable.

Comment: thanks. You can add it as an answer and I check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within template tags, you don't need to mark context variables. They are usually recognized without the braces:

```
<form action="{% url target %}" method="post">
```

should work just fine. Just as you have probably used other tags in a similar way:

```
{% if target %}
# or
{% for obj in object_list %}
```

While some these examples are listed in the docs for template [variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#variables) and [tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#tags), the point is not explicitly made there.

Comment: Moreover it's better to pass a dict in place of `locals()`. For instance, `mycontext = {'target' : 'myurl', 'foo' : 'bar', ...}` and `return (render(request, template, mycontext)`.

Comment: @EdouardThiel Well, `locals()` is a `dict`, but I would also prefer to be explicit about what I pass to the template there. But it has little to do with the issue of the question, so I'll leave it out.