# passing django variables as parameters into href url

Tags: python, django, url, django-views, django-urls

On my home page i want to have 3 links that will redirect the user to a page `('127.0.0.1:8000/person/<str:name>')` which will display the name that they clicked. I would like to use a for loop to create links for these names as i plan to have much more than 3 names.

I have tested with the two methods (for loop / manually writing out all of the links) but can't get the for loop to work.

I thought these two methods below would produce the same result.

```
    <h2>does not work</h2>
    {% for person in people %}
        <a href="{% url 'person' '{{person}}'  %}">{{person}}</a>
    {% endfor %}

    <h2>works</h2>
    <a href="{% url 'person' 'logan' %}">logan</a>
    <a href="{% url 'person' 'paul' %}">paul</a>
    <a href="{% url 'person' 'nicola' %}">nicola</a>
```

What the urls look like in page source:

[image]

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, "APP/home.html", context={"people":['logan', 'paul', 'nicola']})


def person(request, name):
    return render(request, 'APP/person.html', context={"name":name})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('person/<str:name>/', views.person, name='person'),
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django : url tag -> how to use a variable as url\_name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290294/django-url-tag-how-to-use-a-variable-as-url-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `person` variable into `{{}}` signs since in `url` tag you should use it directly:

```
{% for person in people %}
    <a href="{% url 'person' person  %}">{{person}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Check example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url).